# Populate JComboBox with list from another class

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am extremely new to Java. I created a User Form, a dice object and an xml file containing the dicetypes. I was able to parse the XML and store the type in a list but am unable to figure out how to populate a JCombox with the dicetype names. I guess I am looking for a little explanation as to what I am missing.

Below is my code:

```
package dicebag;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import dicebag.ui.userInterface;
import dicebag.util.parseXML;

/**
 * @author troy.a.pilewski
 */
public class mainApp {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    parseXML parseXML = new parseXML();
                    parseXML.parseXML();
                    parseXML.displayDice();
                    System.out.println(parseXML.getDice());
                    parseXML.getDice();
                    userInterface frame = new userInterface();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
package dicebag.util;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * @author troy.a.pilewski
 */
public class dice {
    String type;
    int sides;

    /**
     * @param type
     * @param sides
     */
    public dice(String type, int sides) {
        this.type = type;
        this.sides = sides;

    }

    /**
     * Random Generator for rolling one dice
     * 
     * @param sides
     * @return value
     */
    public int roll(int sides) {
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        int value = randomGen.nextInt(sides) + 1;
        return value;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

```
package dicebag.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * @author troy.a.pilewski
 */
public class parseXML {
    /**
     * Variable declarations
     */
    public static final String xmlFilePath = "./src/dicebag/util/bag.xml";
    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public static List<dice> dice = new ArrayList<dice>();

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void parseXML() {
        try {
            File xmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDoc = db.parse(xmlFile);

            System.out.println("Root Element: " + xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            System.out.println("===============================");

            if (xmlDoc.hasChildNodes()) {
                printNodeList(xmlDoc.getChildNodes());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

    private static void printNodeList(NodeList nodeList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
            Node elemNode = nodeList.item(count);

            if (elemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // Get node name and value
                System.out.println("\nNode Name: " + elemNode.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("Node Content: " + elemNode.getTextContent());

                if (elemNode.hasAttributes()) {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = elemNode.getAttributes();
                    Node xmlNode = nodeMap.item(0);

                    System.out.println("Attribute Name: " + xmlNode.getNodeName());
                    System.out.println("Attribute Value: " + xmlNode.getNodeValue());

                    String type = xmlNode.getNodeValue();
                    String temp = elemNode.getTextContent().substring(elemNode.getTextContent().lastIndexOf('e') + 1);
                    int sides = Integer.parseInt(temp.replaceAll("\\n\\t", ""));

                    dice.add(new dice(type, sides));

                }

                if (elemNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                    // Recursive call if there are child nodes
                    printNodeList(elemNode.getChildNodes());

                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void displayDice() {
        for (int count = 0; count < dice.size(); count++) {
            if (count < dice.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(dice.get(count) + ", ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(dice.get(count));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param dice
     * @return dice
     */
    public List<dice> getDice() {
        return dice;
    }
}
```

```
package dicebag.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import dicebag.util.dice;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/**
 * @author troy.a.pilewski
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class userInterface extends JFrame {

    private static final String dice = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtDiceQty;
    private JTextField txtRollMod;
    private JTextField txtRollTotal;
    private JTable tblRolls;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public userInterface() {
        setTitle("Dicebag");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[:75px:75px][:75px:75px][:75px:75px][:175px:175px]",
                "[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]"));

        JLabel lblRollTotal = new JLabel("Roll Total: ");
        contentPane.add(lblRollTotal, "cell 2 0,alignx leading,growy");

        txtRollTotal = new JTextField();
        txtRollTotal.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(txtRollTotal, "cell 3 0,growx");
        txtRollTotal.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblDiceQty = new JLabel("Dice Qty: ");
        contentPane.add(lblDiceQty, "cell 0 1,alignx leading,growy");

        txtDiceQty = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(txtDiceQty, "cell 1 1,growx");
        txtDiceQty.setColumns(10);

        tblRolls = new JTable();
        tblRolls.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        contentPane.add(tblRolls, "cell 2 1 2 14,grow");

        JLabel lblDiceType = new JLabel("Dice Type: ");
        contentPane.add(lblDiceType, "cell 0 2,alignx leading,growy");

        JComboBox cboDiceType = new JComboBox();
        List<dice> dice = new ArrayList<dice>();
        for (dice d : dice) {
            cboDiceType.addItem(d);
        }
        contentPane.add(cboDiceType, "cell 1 2,growx");

        JLabel lblRollModifier = new JLabel("Roll Modifier: ");
        contentPane.add(lblRollModifier, "cell 0 3,alignx leading,growy");

        txtRollMod = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(txtRollMod, "cell 1 3,growx");
        txtRollMod.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnRoll = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        contentPane.add(btnRoll, "cell 0 4 2 1,grow");
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bag>
    <dice name="D3"><sides>3</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D4"><sides>4</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D6"><sides>6</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D8"><sides>8</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D10"><sides>10</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D12"><sides>12</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D20"><sides>20</sides>
    </dice>
    <dice name="D%"><sides>100</sides>
    </dice>
</bag>
```

Please could someone just give me a little instruction? Also, I am using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Look at what you are adding to the ComboBox. You are adding a List,, not a Dice object. In fact the interface class doesn't have access to the objects read in the XML. Basically have your readXMLFile provide a method to retrieve a List<Dice>, call that and pass that to the mainUserInterface class.'s method. then iterate that list, and pass each Dice object to the combobox

Comment: It is correct, tho, to 1) create a Dice class, with 2) a toString() method, 3 instantiate a bunch of these objects, and 4) add those objects to the JComboBox.

Comment: So how would I go about correcting it?

Comment: add a method to readXMLFile like List<Dice> getDice() { return dice; } and call that method from the main, and pass the results to the mainUserInterface class, as stated.

Comment: then there, do for (Dice d : dice) { cboDiceType.addItem(d); }

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: I made some edits to the files. Could you let me know if I went in the right direction?

Comment: javax.xml.soap.Node.ELEMENT_NODE is the wrong constant

Comment: your readXmlFile looks good, and you call it from mainApplet which is also good. but you don't pass the list gotten from getDice() into the mainInterface class, which is not good. Perhaps your constructor for that class should take a List<Dice> parameter, and then pass that to initialize

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I will try to add the Param into the constructor later tonight and repost. Thanks

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: I have been working on trying to fix the code as you have explained. I think that I am hung up on passing the result of getDice() to the userInterface. Could you please explain how that works to me?